# Efficient way to parse datetime

Tags: javascript

If I have an array as the following

```
var year = 2018;
var date = ["6/06", "03:00", "PM"];
```

how can I efficiently parse it so that I want to do

```
var year = 2018;
var parsedDate = Date.UTC(year, 5, 6, 15, 0);
```

Note that the month is zero-based.

Answer (score -1):

Just some operations on the array should do it:

```
let [daymonth, hourmin, ampm] = date;
let [day, month] = daymonth.split("/");
let [hour, min] = hourmin.split(":");
if(ampm === "PM") hour = +hour + 12;
const parsedDate = new Date(year, month - 1, +day, +hour, +min);
```

Comment: You should really expand on your answer a bit. It is also probably worth mentioning the various features and their browser support. Finally you hard-coded "pm" which will fail for their example

Comment: @marie i put as much effort into answering as the OP puts into asking.

Comment: Just because the question is low effort doesn't mean you should answer with low effort. Imo if you don't want to put effort in don't bother answering.